# F# native call in Task throws exception, bypasses exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, exception, f#, native

I have an F# application that uses native libraries.

The code roughly looks like this

```ml
let exceptionHandler (sender:obj) (e:UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) =
    let msg = (e.ExceptionObject :?> Exception).Message
    printfn "An unhandled exception in \n Message:%s" msg
    Environment.Exit(1)

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.AddHandler (new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(exceptionHandler))



[|(*Some array*)|]
|> Array.map (fun (_) -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () ->
try
   (* a lot of native libraries calls  that can fail with a bunch of exceptions *)
with
   | ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message))
|> Task.WaitAll
```

The 'Try` block executes in a loop and after some time (a couple of hours) I get "*.exe has stopped working" dialog, with the information that the faulting module is some native library that my code references.

Before I start with dump debugging: any ideas why my `catch` block didn't catch the exception, or why the `UnhandledException` handler didn't report anything? Any ideas how can I survive all the exceptions thrown by native libs (in this case probably a simple retry will solve the problem).

(Note I added C# tag because most probably this isn't solely F# related, but more a .NET issue).

(Note II, yes I am aware that try catch everything is not the best solution :))

Comment: Out of interest - how big is `Some Array` and are you tracking memory usage as this runs?

Comment: Array is not that big but I eat a lot of memory in the try loop so memory is a possible problem. But still, should we catch something like OutOfMemoryException or whatever native library throws when it doesn't have enough memory?

Comment: That's the thing - you can't expect to be able to catch an `OutOfMemoryException`, better to do some profiling and determine how many tasks you can safely run side by side, and limit the pool to this size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: profile to see how much memory is consumed by one task, and then decide (based on anticipated memory available) how many you can run side by side.

[this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351) gives advice on how to set a limit to number of concurrent threads in TPL

Answer (score 2):

Some exceptions can't be caught,  `StackOverflowException` is one of them.

.NET also allow to terminate a process using `Environment.FailFast` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You will need to dump debugging to be sure of what is happening.